# how to pass a variable to another view iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have viewA and viewB inside of a containerview.

I passed Var from a viewA to the containerviewcontroller by delegate.  I need to pass it from my containerviewcontroller to tableviewcontroller.  I tried two ways, one way i was able to pass it, but I can't gain access to the viewA inside of the container view.  I can open viewA with the second way, but the Var doesn't get passed.

Please help.

My storyboard flow is as follow.

containerview -> tabbarviewcontroller ->navigationviewcontroller -> tableviewcontroller

```
(void)openSavedProjectAt:(NSNumber *)index
{
    //delegate from another class   
    // works, and index value gets passed, but menu button doesn't work after, cuz didn't push with container?
    /*
    IncomeViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"incomeList"];
    [incomeNav pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    vc.projectIndexToOpen = index;
    */  
    // the value doesn't get passed, but everything else works
    /*
    IncomeViewController *vc = [[IncomeViewController alloc]init];    
    vc.projectIndexToOpen = index;
    */    
    [self menuButtonPushed]; // close side menu
}
```

Comment: Its NOT a duplicate - he know how to pass, its that he's having problems with it, that is his question, not how to in general, why he's having problems in his specific case.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your structure,

containerview -> tabbarviewcontroller ->navigationviewcontroller -> tableViewController

think about the relationships you have and put them together. The tabBarController is the containerViewController's childViewControllers[0] (assuming that you have only one child). The navigation controller is one of the controllers in the tab bar controller's viewControllers array -- if it's the first one then viewControllers[0]. The table view controller is the navigation controller's topViewController, so putting that all together, you get,

```
TableViewController *tvc = (TableViewController *)[(UINavigationController *)[(UITabBarController *)self.childViewControllers[0] viewControllers][0] topViewController];
```

That's kind of ugly to parse, so it would be easier to read as multiple lines,

```
UITabBarController *tbc = self.childViewControllers[0];
UINavigationController *nav = tbc.viewControllers[0];
TableViewController *tvc = (TableViewController *)nav.topViewController;
```

With the tvc reference, you can now pass the object you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Seems to work, but I'm not sure if the Var has been passed, is there a way to reload the whole talbeviewcontroller?

Comment: @gt3240, if you want to reload the whole table, use [self.tableView reloadData];

Comment: reloadData only reloads the table, is there a method to reload the whole view?

Comment: @gt3240, sorry, I misread your question. Why do you wan to reload the whole controller? What else do you need to do there other than updating the table view?

Comment: I need to update a variable which is used in the tableview to load the correct contents.

Comment: @gt3240, which you do by passing the new value to that variable using the reference tvc. You don't need to reload the whole controller to do that.

Comment: I have a list in the side menu. When I select a row, it send a nsnumber to the tableviewcontroller to show the correct list.  However, the nsnumber gets passed, but the nsnumber is already loaded in the tvc, so I want to reload that with the new one.  Thanks for the help.